# Matching flex distance for heading of table and content

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a table with heading and entries under it.

[image: the issue image]

I want the heading and entries aligned with each other.

Table.jsx:

```
<div className="home-trending">
      <h1 className="home-trending-heading"> CRYPTO TRENDING ON DEX</h1>
      <div className="cex-trending-data">
        <div className="dex-content-heading bold">
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Chain</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Token Amount (out)</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Token Amount (in)</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">TXN Value</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Wallet Type</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Time</p>
          <p className="cex-content-heading-item">Twitter</p>
        </div>
        {topDEXTrades.slice(0, 10).map((trade) => {
          return (
            <TrendingDexRows
              chain={trade.chain_name}
              time={trade.trade_time}
              token_out={trade.token_out}
              token_in={trade.token_in}
              trade_id={trade.id}
              symbol_out={trade.symbol_out}
              symbol_in={trade.symbol_in}
              value={trade.txn_value}
              hash={trade.txn_hash}
              wallet={trade.wallet}
              category={trade.category}
              timeToGo={timeToGoSec}
              href={twitterHref}
              detailedView={true}
              view="large"
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Table.css:

```
.dex-content-heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Rows.jsx:

```
<div>
      <div className="cex-trending-row">
        <div className="cex-trending-row-name row-item">
          <img
            src={chainIcon(props.chain)}
            alt="btc"
            className="base-asset-img"
          />
          <p className="trending-symbol">{props.chain}</p>
        </div>
        <p className="row-item bold">{millify(props.token_out)}</p>
        <p className="row-item bold">{millify(props.token_in)}</p>
        <p className="row-item bold">{millify(props.value)}</p>
        <p className="row-item" style={categoryStyle(props.category)}>
          {categoryName(props.category)}
        </p>
        <p className="row-item"> {props.timeToGo(props.time)}</p>
        <div>
          <a
            href={props.href(
              props.value,
              props.token_out,
              props.token_in,
              props.chain,
              props.symbol_out,
              props.symbol_in
            )}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", paddingRight: "25px" }}
          >
            <img
              src={Twitter}
              alt="twitter"
              className="graph-icon-img-dex"
              style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr className="horrizontal-line" />
    </div>
```

Row.css:

```
.cex-trending-row {
  display: flex;
}
.row-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

The heading and the rows are not aligned with each other. How do I make sure they are perfectly aligned? Which flex property can be used to make sure both divs have the same amount of space between the items of the div?

Comment: might be a good usecase for `display: grid`, or a table display / table element

Comment: What other properties would I need to align them using grid?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using grid with React.

```js
const App = () => {
    const headingData = [
      "Chain",
      "Token",
      "Title 3",
      "EzPz",
    ];
    const dataArr = [
      { chain: "curve", token: "4m", foo: "bar", lemon: "squeezy" },
      { chain: "bird", token: "5m", foo: "tar", lemon: "teasy" },
      { chain: "lard", token: "1m", foo: "guitar", lemon: "jeezy" },
      { chain: "hard", token: "20k", foo: "blar", lemon: "measly" },
      { chain: "charged", token: "ayyyy", foo: "mars", lemon: "⚰" },
    ];
  
    return (
        <div className="myGrid">
          {
            headingData.map(str => <div key={"head-" + str}>{str}</div>)
          }
          {
            dataArr.map((o,i) => [
              <div key={"data-chain-"+i}>{o.chain}</div>,
              <div key={"data-token-"+i}>{o.token}</div>,
              <div key={"data-foo-"+i}>{o.foo}</div>,
              <div key={"data-lemon-"+i}>{o.lemon}</div>,
            ])
          }
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```css
.myGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```